При создании нового элемента забывается предыдущий. Python Tkinter
Пытаюсь получить значение из entry31, но при создании второго, первый не читается, а нужно получать со всех созданных кнопкой текстовых полей.
class Twolist():
    def __init__(self):
        x_pos = 10
        y_pos = 0 
        self.x_pos = x_pos
        self.y_pos = y_pos
    def create_sopr(self):
        self.x_pos += 0
        self.y_pos += 200
        text_y = self.y_pos - 95
        
        

        entry31 = Text(frame2, width =22, height = 6,wrap=WORD, relief=FLAT)
        self.entry31 = entry31
        entry31.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
        entry31.insert("1.0", " ")
        entry31.tag_add("center", 1.0, "end")
        entry31.pack()
        frame2.create_window((self.x_pos + 150,  self.y_pos), window=entry31 )
        frame2.create_text(self.x_pos + 85,  text_y, anchor=NW, text= "Информация о \n наряде сопровождения",justify="center")

twolist = Twolist()

def data_save():
    print(twolist.entry31.get("1.0", END))

btn_save =  Button(text='Экспортировать доклад', font='Times_New_Roman 20 bold ' )
btn_save.config(command=data_save)
btn_save.pack()
frame2.create_window((290, 550), window=btn_save)


#ВТОРАЯ ВКЛАДКА
new_sopr_btn = Button(text='Добавить сопровождение',font='Times_New_Roman 20 bold ')
new_sopr_btn.config(command=twolist.create_sopr)
new_sopr_btn.pack()
frame2.create_window((500, 60), window=new_sopr_btn )





Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
